# Align view and Text for responsive screen in React Native

Tags: react-native

[image]

I want to align all view and text parts like the above image. if the number may be big or small but the upper title should be in the middle of the value.

same alignment for the right side views also.

and the view and alignment should be responsive for every ios and android.
I have tried:

```js
<ZekifutSchumView>
 <ZekifutSchumText>סה”כ</ZekifutSchumText>
</ZekifutSchumView>
```

```js
<HefreshimForLoTashlumView>
        <HefreshimForLoTashlumText>
          {props.hefreshimTotalForLoTashlum}
        </HefreshimForLoTashlumText>
      </HefreshimForLoTashlumView>
```

```js
const ZekifutSchumText = styled(Text)``;
const ZekifutSchumView = styled(View)`
  right: 2px;
`;
const HefreshimForLoTashlumView = styled(View)`
  top: 15px;
  ${Platform.select({
    ios: `
      right:  30px;
    `,
    android: `
      right: 26px;
    `,
  })};
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-color: #ddd;
  height: 18px;
`;
const HefreshimForLoTashlumText = styled(Text)`
  ${Platform.select({
    ios: `
    right:  20px;
  `,
    android: `
    right: 21px;
  `,
  })};
`;
```

The same code is for the right side view also.

How can I align these view??

Comment: give some started code as to what you have tried, it will help in giving solution

Comment: now you can check

Answer (score 0):

```js
    <View style={styles.app}>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}}>
        <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <Text>$</Text>
          <Text>123,345,77</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{
          height: '50%',
          width: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'grey',
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 0}}/>
        <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <Text>$</Text>
          <Text>123,345,77</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
```

Note: pls do not use inline styles, just added them here for easy viewing